# How can I package chaincode into cds format without using IBP vscode extension

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm writing smartcontracts in hyperledger fabric and for deployment purpose I need to package it into cds(chaincodedeploymentspec) format. are there any options other than vscode IBP extension for this?

Answer (score 2):

CDS is the standard format used by Fabric.  The IBP extension does generate packages with the `.cds` file extension, but there's actually nothing special about format.  For example, if you used the CLI package command and named the output file with the `.cds` file extension, then you'd be able to simply use that package.

For example, if you run
`peer chaincode package -p github.com/mycc -n mycc -v 1.0 mycc.cds`

you can then use the `mycc.cds` file anywhere you can use the package created by the IBP extension (for example in the IBP console)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my chaincode uses "shim" package. What needs to be done to create a CDS package for this?

Comment: what language are you using?